# Multiplicación de matrices resultado inesperado C

Tags: c

el ejercicio trata de multiplicar dos matrices en la que das las dimensiones por `scanf` y los vectores también. El problema viene cuando printeas el resultado aparece una matriz de ceros y de dimension muy diferente a la que debería salir.

He probado a cambiar los bucles `for` del la parte en que imprime la matriz producto, así como la parte de la multiplicación de la matriz. Pero no ha hecho efecto.

terMatriz es la matriz producto.

Adjunto el código:

```
  #include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    int m ;
    int n;
    int p;
    
    printf("Numero de filas primera matriz:\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Numero de columnas de primera matriz:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Numero de columnas segunda matriz\n");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    int primMatriz[m][n];
    int secMatriz[n][p];

    printf("ponga primera matriz:\n");

    for(int i = 0; i<m;i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j<n; j++){
            scanf("%d", &primMatriz[i][j]);
            
        }
    }

    printf("ponga segunda matriz:\n");

    for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j<p; j++){
            scanf("%d", &secMatriz[i][j]);
            
        }
    }

    int terMatriz[n][n];

    for(int b = 0; b< p; b++){
        for(int i = 0; i<m; i++){
            int res = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j< n;j++){
                res += primMatriz[i][j] * secMatriz[j][b];
            }
            terMatriz[i][b] = res;
        }
        
    }
    

    printf("El resultado es: \n");

    for(int i =0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<n ; j++){
            printf("%d  ",terMatriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: La segunda matriz es de tamaño `n`, `p`. Probablemente copiaste y pegaste y te olvidaste de cambiar los límites.

Comment: Tienes razón, pero aun asi me da el mismo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un error conceptual.

La multiplicación entre una matriz de dimensiones AxB y otra BxC da una matriz de dimensiones AxC.

Por lo tanto el código debería ser:

```
int terMatriz[m][p];

...   

printf("El resultado es: \n");

for(int i =0; i<m; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<p; j++){
        printf("%d  ", terMatriz[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

El resto del código está bien.